# JavaFX | IntelliJ Idea| ImageView doesn't show image shown in SceneBuilder and it's preview

Tags: java, image, javafx, imageview, scenebuilder

I'm new in JavaFX, so I don't understand what's wrong. I've added images to `ImageView`s in SceneBuilder. In SceneBuilder and it's preview we can see them. But when I run my application, only empty windows is shown (Visually, the canvases sizes are different)

Main.java:

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("MainMenu.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("MainMenu");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

MainMenu.fxml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="720.0" prefWidth="1280.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.MainMenuController">
    <children>
        <ImageView fx:id="background" fitHeight="720.0" fitWidth="1280.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
         <image>
            <Image url="@../../assets/mainMenuScreen/background.png" />
         </image></ImageView>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Tried this in Eclipse - it works as it should

**Project structure**
[image: Project Structure]

[SceneBuilder View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thY7A.jpg)

[Running View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2gd0.png)

P.S. I can set the image by using `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource()`, but the canvas size is still bigger than it set. And path's the same as used in SceneBuilder

Comment: You set the `fitHeight` and `fitWidth` in the `FXML`. Do you set it in the code?

Comment: SceneBuilder uses the relative paths in the file system to create the path. When the application is deployed however, the (compiled) contents of both `src` and `assets` are copied to the root of the classpath. (At least that's how most IDEs deploy the project.) This means at runtime the correct path for the image would be `url="@../mainMenuScreen/background.png"`

Comment: Unfortunately, it still doesn't work. I receive "Cannot resolve directory/file" and the application runs with empty window

Answer (score 0):

It's because of path. I don't know how to do it from fxml (I tried).
Just do it from code

1) init fx:id for your ImageView like `fx:id="imView"`

2) init it in code and set image. (create folder 'resources' in src)

```
@FXML
private ImageView imView;

@FXML
public void initialize(){
    imView.setImage(
            new Image("resources/yourImage.jpg")
    );
}
```

If you also wanna your image be always fit to window size, you should add listeners to it:

Imagine that your ImageView is inside AnchorPane

```
@FXML
private AnchorPane root;

@FXML
private ImageView imView;

@FXML
public void initialize(){
    imView.setImage(
            new Image("ims/Weissmanscore.jpg")
    );
    root.heightProperty().addListener(
            h -> imView.setFitHeight(
                    root.getHeight()
            )
    );
    root.widthProperty().addListener(
            h -> imView.setFitWidth(
                    root.getWidth()
            )
    );
}
```

If you want your Image not to maintain proportions and resize axactly with window just set preserveRatio to false in FXML `preserveRatio="true"` of in code `imView.setPreserveRatio(false);`

Comment: Thanks for answer. It works this way, I've tried it before posting. But the size of the window is still bigger than it should be. I guess, SceneBuilder and the project itself see the right path, but somehow the image isn't shown